# While implementing Firebase Phone Auth I get a strage black bar animation from the top

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin

I'm new to Android. I'm currently trying to implement Firebase Phone Auth in my Kotlin project. I noticed a strage thing happens while waiting for the callback (a black bar animates from  the top of the screen). I'm not doing it in my code and have no idea how to get rid of it. Any ideas what I should do?

[image]

````
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.a9ts.a9ts.databinding.RegisterBinding
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException
import com.google.firebase.auth.*
import org.jetbrains.anko.toast
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class Register : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : RegisterBinding
    private lateinit var callbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = RegisterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.buttonNext.setOnClickListener {
            val phoneNumber = binding.editTextPhoneNumber.text.toString().trim()
            if (phoneNumber.isEmpty())
            {
              binding.editTextPhoneNumber.setError("Number is required!")
              binding.editTextPhoneNumber.requestFocus()
            } else {
              startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber)
            }
        }

        callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                toast("Success!")
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                toast("onVerificationFailed")
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(verificationId: String,token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
                toast("SMS Code sent: $verificationId")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber: String) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber, // Phone number to verify
            60, // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Unit of timeout
            this, // Activity (for callback binding)
            callbacks) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is causing the behavior as such, but going back to BOM 25.12.0 solved the issue.

```
//implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
```